# how to neutralize stannous chloride (50ml) to make it safe for disposal

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

I made a small quantity of stannous chloride by dissolving tin in muriatic acid - I would like to neutralize it for safe disposal - will mixing it with soda bicarbonate dissolved in water accomplish this? and if not then what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "safe disposal".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Adding sodium bicarbonate will produce a white precipitate of $\ce{Sn(OH)2}$ that will be slowly oxidized by air into $\ce{SnO2}$. And $\ce{SnO2}$ is totally insoluble, as it is the formula of the cassiterite, most important mineral used to extract tin on Earth.